# What's a pythonic way to generate an array with a diagonal edge?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension, numpy-ndarray

I created an array with a diagonal edge by using two for loops, but I wonder if there is a simpler way to do so, for example with a list comprehension:

```
im_diag = np.zeros((im_size, im_size), dtype=np.int8)

for x in range(im_size):
    for y in range(im_size):
        if x+y >= im_size:
            im_diag[x,y] = 1
```

Output (`im_size = 5`):

```
>>> im_size
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 5):

In general when using numpy, it's far better to use a vectorised method, which will become a lot faster than methods using loops and list-comprehensions as the size of the desired array increases.

```
>>> np.flip(np.tril(np.ones((5,5)), k=-1), 1)
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

[np.ones](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) to create an array of `1`s,

[np.tril](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) to create a lower triangular array

[np.flip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) to horizontally flip the array

**Time Comparison with other answers:**

[image]

As shown, with `n>=10`, the numpy method is faster, and as n gets larger, this method will tend to be about 10 times faster than list comprehension solutions.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def cdjb(n):
    return np.flip(np.tril(np.ones((n,n)), k=-1), 1)

def displayname(n):
    return [[int(j > i) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)][::-1]

def MikeMajara(n):
    return [[1 if i+j >= n else 0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: n,
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(14)],
    kernels=[
        cdjb,displayname,MikeMajara
        ],
    xlabel='Size of Array',
    )
```

Comment: In that case I would say that should be part of your answer then. There is no obvious way of telling at first sight for (specially for learners). I would also state the downside is readability because nowhere in the question was efficiency or big array dimensions mentioned, but still _advanced_ functions of a library are used and linked to. For this reason, IMHO, the best approach is the OPs post, unless efficiency was at stake.

Comment: @MikeMajara I've added a time comparison graph. Your list comprehension solution is faster than the other one, (+1) but numpy will still beat both for n larger than 10.

Answer (score 2):

With list comprehension (no `numpy` required):

```
n = 5
[[int(j > i) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)][::-1]
```

Gives

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

where `[::-1]` just reverses the outer list.

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking for a comprehension list this could be your solution:

```
[[1 if i+j >= im_size else 0 for i in range(im_size)] for j in range(im_size)]
```

But complex comprehension lists are harder to read/understand. And unreadable code is not pythonic. So give it a thought.